# Cancel Jenkins job upon receviving a new one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job (pipeline) that updates the status page. The job is triggered externally. I want a currently running job to be stopped/cancelled is a new is scheduled.
Is there an option for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we use. It doesn't stop *this* build, but lets *the other* (newer) build to stop this one. In the end, this ensures that a newer build is allowed to proceed while an older build is stopped, so this may fit you.

```
// invoke early in your pipeline
def killOtherBuilds() {
    def jobname = env.JOB_NAME
    def my_buildnum = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger()
    echo "Job is ${jobname}, build number is ${my_buildnum}"

    def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobname)
    def builds = job.builds
    job = null
    for (build in builds) {
        this_buildnum = build.getNumber().toInteger()
        if (!build.isBuilding()) {
            println "Build ${this_buildnum} isn't building."
            continue; 
        }
        if (my_buildnum == this_buildnum)
        { 
            println "Build ${this_buildnum} is building and it's this build."
            continue; 
        }
        else if (my_buildnum < this_buildnum)
        { 
            errorMsg = "A newer build is already scheduled"
            currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
            currentBuild.description = errorMsg
            error(errorMsg)
        }

        echo "Kill build ${build} number ${this_buildnum}."
        build.displayName += "(stopped by #${my_buildnum})"
        killBuild(build)
        Thread.sleep(5000)
    }
}

@NonCPS
def killBuild(some_build){
    some_build.doStop()
}
```

Stopping *this* build can involve checking frequently if a newer build is already scheduled, you may want to modify this according to your exact requirements.

Comment: Right. In my case, I have a limit of one job a time. It means that the next job will not even start until the current one is complete. I wanted that Jenkins to kill running job when it sees a new one.